# Authorization in Asp.net Core 2.0 with maria database?

Tags: asp.net

When a User logins into a Web application. The Website has to authenticate who the User against the Database. Once the User is authenticated then a system can authorise the person so that they can make request to other pages without logging in again. I am having a implementing security into my asp.net core 2.0 web application, because I am not using Entity Framework. I am using MariaDB as the database Back-End. When a request is made to the Server

```
     public ViewResult testMethod(LoginModel model){

  User user = dataManager.GetUser(model.Email);

                if (user == null)
                {

                   // return user to view 
            return View(model);
                }

                if (user.Activated != true)
                {
                 // return user to view 
                    return View(model);
                }   

        // Use userManager
```

I want to use the UserManager but since I am using a MariaDB as the backend is this still possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using, entity framework

let say you have table User with password
try using claim principal

```
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {           

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = _authService.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var userClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Mail),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.PositionId)
                };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "Ix");
                    //userClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "0"));
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("app", principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false });

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```